# Alternate way to write in a file instead of using "<<" in c++?

Tags: c++, fstream, file-handling, getline

When we load a file using fstream header, we use `>>` and `getline()` to get one complete line.

When writing it to an output file we use `<<`

Is there any other alternate way to write the line in the output file instead of `<<`?

Comment: Firstly, `>>` is not restricted to **one character**. Secondly, why do you want an alternative to `<<`.

Comment: For knowledge, I think there is no limit to what we can achieve in programming, why restricted to just one method only .. !!

Comment: Check out this article then. You'd have much to explore after that: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/#binary_files `read/write` is surely which you need. But its preferable to use them in binary files only.

Comment: a very informative read, thank you @brc-dd 
Why it is preferable to binary files only .. ???

Comment: That's because these functions are designed by keeping binary files in mind. If you're using them on text file, then it's most likely that you'll get unformatted text if you open that text file with an text editor. This is mainly because these functions copy bit by bit data of from buffer to the file and ignore system-specific endline conversions.

Comment: so does this mean if we use them for txt files, they reduce efficiency ?

Comment: No that wouldn't take longer. In fact read and write are faster. What I am saying is that they are unformatted. What you're writing using `write`, you'll have to read using `read` to avoid errors. You won't be able to manually read the file by opening it in some text editor. It defies the sole purpose of using a test file.

Comment: Write is quite useful if you've to print a `char` array to file, but it is not that for other data types. For example if you're trying to write an integer, then you'll have to first convert it to a char array. You can statically cast it into char* but that would not be of any use as it will not be human readable. You need to use `read()` to get back that information you've written or use something like `itoa()` before write operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is very simple. look the code below

```
#include <iostream>
  using namespace std;

  int main()
    {
     char a('a');
     // cout
      cout.put(a);   // can only be used for characters
      string hello;
     //cin
       cin.getline(hello);
    //or
       getline(cin,hello);
    }
```

see, it was too easy;

Answer (score 0):

You can use `put` [link here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/put/) and `write` [link here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/write/) as an alternative.

```
 // single character
char character;
cout.put(character);

//For string
char * buffer = new char[size];
cout.write(buffer, size);
```

So for your case check out `write` in C++.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: @NumaanJaved If you find the answer useful, kindly accept the answer for the benefit of future users as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also `#include <cstdio>` and go for the C API, i.e. using fopen/printf...

See doc : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdio

Comment: how to open a file .. and how to give output  .... are not related to my question 
I am asking about writing into a file ... is there a way to do so with cstdio ?

Comment: fwrite :https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fwrite or printf variants https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf or (per char) putc https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fputc